# A numpy function that lists all the possible "coordinates" in a nd-array

Tags: python, numpy

**Is there a `numpy` function that lists all the possible "coordinates" in a `numpy.ndarray`?**

It would do exactly what this function `all_possible_coordinates` does:

```py
import numpy as np

def all_possible_coordinates(shape): 
    return np.array([item.ravel() for item in np.meshgrid(*(np.arange(n) for n in shape))]).T

def test_all_possible_coordinates():
    shape = (1, 2, 2)
    assert np.all(all_possible_coordinates(shape)
                  == np.array([[0, 0, 0],
                               [0, 0, 1],
                               [0, 1, 0],
                               [0, 1, 1]]))

test_all_possible_coordinates()
```

#### EDIT: solution 1, by M Z

```py
def all_possible_coordinates(shape): 
    return np.argwhere(np.ones(shape))
```

#### EDIT: solution 2, by Warren Weckesser

```py
def all_possible_coordinates(shape):
    return np.array(list(np.ndindex(shape)))
```

Comment: Not sure if there is one, but you could just make it: `def all_possible_coordinates(shape): np.argwhere(np.ones(shape))`

Comment: `argwhere` is just `np.transpose(np.nonzero())`.   For indexing an array, the tuple of arrays produced by `nonzero` is generally more useful than this transpose.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`numpy.ndindex`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndindex.html):

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: list(np.ndindex(1, 2, 2))
Out[2]: [(0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 1), (0, 1, 0), (0, 1, 1)]

In [3]: for idx in np.ndindex(2, 3, 2):
   ...:     print(idx)
   ...: 
(0, 0, 0)
(0, 0, 1)
(0, 1, 0)
(0, 1, 1)
(0, 2, 0)
(0, 2, 1)
(1, 0, 0)
(1, 0, 1)
(1, 1, 0)
(1, 1, 1)
(1, 2, 0)
(1, 2, 1)
```